# Keeping a TCP connection alive in a goroutine and check if it timesout if the connection is lost

Tags: tcp, error-handling, go, server, goroutine

I have a TCP server up and running listetning to a port and a go routine for handeling the connections. I wonder if it's possible to have a go routine running for every connection keeping them alive with `net.SetKeepAlive(true)`. Also with error handling so that if the connection times out it will execute cleanup functions like removing the connection from a list?

Handle routine:

```
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn, rec chan string) {
   var item QueItem
   buf := make([]byte, bufSize)
   l, err := conn.Read(buf)
   if err != nil || l < 0 {
    fmt.Println("Error reading from conn: ", conn)
    fmt.Println("Error reading: ", err)
   }

   err = json.Unmarshal(buf[:l], &item)
   if err != nil {
     fmt.Println("Error converting to JSON", jErr)
   }

  fmt.Printf("Received : %+v\n", item)
  fmt.Println("recived from:", conn.RemoteAddr())
  rec <- item.IP
}
```

TCPserver:

```
for {
    conn, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("No accept", err)
        log.Println("Unable to accept connection", err)
    }
    go handleConnection(conn, recived)
}
```

Comment: That's not how TCP keepalive works. You turn it on, and will receive an error from the TCP stack. You don't need another goroutine to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep a check on the established TCP connections, one can do `keep-alive` mechanism in two ways.

At application level:
  In idle conditions both client and server agree on  a protocol to send pre-determined packets to each other. Lack of a message from peer with in certain time can signal a problem in the connection.

At TCP layer:
Enable the TCP stack to check the connection status. The TCP layer at which this mechanism is enabled will send `keep-alive` messages at regular determined interval. It would expect that the peer TCP stack send `keep-alive-ack`. Absence of ACK after needed re-transmission signals connection problem and the application would be duly notified.

I think `net.SetKeepAlive(true)` is a `go` way of informing the TCP to do keep-alive. You need not do any thing special constructs in go routine.

TCP `keep-alive` works well. Application need not be burdened to check for connection status

Comment: Hi @Prabhu,
Seems `net` doesn't have any public function like `SetKeepAlive` .